# Initialize static function pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to declare a class-member function pointer as static so it can be called by a static member function, and assign the pointer to a function passed to the constructor.

So far I haven't been able to get it working, is this somehow possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

//external callback function
static void innerFunc(int i, float f){
    printf("running inner function : %i %f\n", i, f);
}

class A{
// member function pointer
typedef void (A::*cbPtr)(int, float);
static cbPtr cbptr;

public:

//constructor
A(void(*func)(int, float))
{
   A::cbptr = func; // < this doesn't work
}

void run()
{    
   memberFunc(5, 4.4, NULL, NULL);    
} 

private:
// static member function
static void memberFunc(int i, float f, void* a, const void* aa)
{
    printf("running outer function.\n");
  //  cbptr(i, f);  // << I want to be able to call the function here

}

};

int main() {

    A a(innerFunc);
    a.run();   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Static members don't have access to specific instances of an object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `A::cbPtr` type expects a pointer to a non-static member function of the `A` class.  But you are trying to assign a pointer to a non-member function to your static `cbptr` variable.  They are two different types, that is why the code does not compile.

Drop the `A::` from your `cbPtr` typedef, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//external callback function
static void innerFunc(int i, float f)
{
    printf("running inner function : %i %f\n", i, f);
}

class A
{
public:
    // non-member function pointer
    typedef void (*cbPtr)(int, float);

    //constructor
    A(cbPtr func)
    {
        m_cbptr = func;
    }

    void run()
    {    
        memberFunc(5, 4.4, NULL, NULL);    
    } 

private:
    static cbPtr m_cbptr;

    // static member function
    static void memberFunc(int i, float f, void* a, const void* aa)
    {
        printf("running outer function.\n");
        m_cbptr(i, f);
    }
};

A::cbPtr A::m_cbptr = NULL;

int main()
{
    A a(innerFunc);
    a.run();   
    return 0;
}
```

When you learn how to separate your declarations and definitions into `.h` and `.cpp` files, it would look more like this instead:

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

class A
{
public:
    // non-member function pointer
    typedef void (*cbPtr)(int, float);

    //constructor
    A(cbPtr func);

    void run();

private:
    static cbPtr m_cbptr;

    // static member function
    static void memberFunc(int i, float f, void* a, const void* aa);
};

#endif
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <stdio.h>

A::cbPtr A::m_cbptr = NULL;

A::A(A::cbPtr func)
{
    m_cbptr = func;
}

void A::run()
{    
    memberFunc(5, 4.4, NULL, NULL);    
} 

void A::memberFunc(int i, float f, void* a, const void* aa)
{
    printf("running outer function.\n");
    m_cbptr(i, f);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//external callback function
static void innerFunc(int i, float f)
{
    printf("running inner function : %i %f\n", i, f);
}

int main()
{
    A a(innerFunc);
    a.run();   
    return 0;
}
```

Either way, just know that because `m_cbptr` is `static`, multiple instances of `A` will share the same variable, so you won't be able to have separate callbacks for different `A` objects.  If `memberFunc()` were not `static`, or if its `a` or `aa` parameter is a user-defined value that can be set to point at the `A` object's `this` pointer, then you can have a separate callback per object.

Comment: Also suggested: `std::function<void(int,float)>`?

Comment: If C++11 or later were being used, yes.  But the question was not tagged as such.

Comment: That worked! I have one question, I'm a bit of a c++ noob what is this line? A::cbPtr A::cbptr = NULL doing, is there a term I could search for to get a better understanding?

Comment: @oraz cbPtr is the type, m_cbptr is the object, A:: is the namespace in which to look for cbPtr and m_cbptr

Comment: @oraz: since `m_cbptr` is `static`, you need to declare an actual variable for it, outside of the class declaration, so the linker can find it. And since the variable and its type both belong to the `A` class, you have to quality both names with `A::` so the compiler can find them. So, `cbPtr` is the variable type, `m_cbptr` is the variable name, `A::` is where to look for `cbPtr` and `m_cbptr`, and `NULL` is the variable's initial value.

Comment: @oraz: If you had separated your code into `.h` and `.cpp` files, the `static` declaration would go in the `.h` file and the variable definition would go in the `.cpp` file. But, in your example, you have everything in a single file, but that does not change the requirements. You still need to define the variable somewhere. I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: [why would you assume that the OP is using tools 7 years out of date?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/is-it-safe-to-assume-c11-by-now-even-if-the-question-is-not-tagged-as-such)

Comment: @MooingDuck: Because most developers I deal with don't have a C++11 compiler, or don't know/use newer C++11 features (and partly because I myself don't use it, either). So, unless told otherwise, I don't assume questioners are using C++11. I might sometimes include C++11 solutions in my answers, but I will also target older codes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I acknowledge that many don't use newer C++11 features, but along the same vein that many don't use C++ features and stick to C-ish. I would be surprised if most developers don't have a C++11 compiler though.  As a Q&A site, we should probably err on the side of educating about newer features, rather than ignoring them.

Comment: I am using c++11 so I might look into how the same problem of a static function pointer would be solved with std::function, but I am making a library wrapper that I hope others can use, so it's actually good to have a general purpose solution that doesn't require any extra compiler flags

Comment: @oraz: "*I am using c++11*" - then, please include the [tag:c++11] tag in your future questions. "*I am making a library wrapper*" - I am assuming that `memberfunc()` is a callback for that library, is that right? If so, is its `a` or `aa` parameter a user-defined value that you can assign the `A` object's `this` pointer to? If so, then `m_cbptr` does not need to be `static` anymore, `memberfunc()` would be able to cast the parameter to `A*` to access non-static members.

Comment: @RemyLebeau memberfunc() is the callback that is usually called by the library (portaudio) and the inner function is a simplified callback (omitting 2 parameters). The main callback is usually external and is passed to a portaudio function PaOpenstream, but to encapsulate the simple callback I have it inside the class. I did try at first having the main callback non-static, but could not get it to work otherwise when I passed a reference to the openstream function.

Comment: @oraz the main library callback must be a standalone function or a class `static` member, but `pa_OpenStream()` does have a `userData` parameter that is passed to the callback. Use that parameter to pass the class `this` pointer to the callback, then the callback can access non-static class members. You are making things more complicated then they need to be.